# A simple proof that a plane similarity without fixed points is an isometry

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Is there a (relatively) simple proof of the fact that a plane similarity without fixed points is an isometry?

In the literature it is usually formulated as "a non-isometric similarity has a fixed point" and the proof is somewhat involved, using the concept of directed distance. I am looking for something simpler, to use for the classification of plane similarities.

A simple proof of the above-mentioned classification will also do.

Comment: If there is a relatively simple proof, you'd think "a non-isometric similarity has a fixed point" would be an immediate consequence (via proof by contradiction), as opposed to requiring an involved proof.

Comment: Put it this way - the standard way of deducing the classification is to use that a similarity $s$ can be written as a composition $s=i\circ\sigma$, where $\sigma$ is a stretch and $i$ is an isometry. $\sigma$ has a fixed-point, and the fixed-point property of $s$ rules out translation and glide reflection as an option for $i$ when $\sigma\neq Id$. If one can deal with these two cases for $i$ directly - then one does not need the fixed point property for classification and can just derive it as a consequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A similarity can be expressed as:
$$
s(\vec x)=rA\vec x+\vec t,
$$
where $r$ is the scale factor, $A$ is an orthogonal matrix and $\vec t$ is a translation vector. If $s(\vec x)=\vec x$ then:
$$
\vec x=(I-rA)^{-1}\vec t,
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix. Hence a fixed point doesn't exist only if $I-rA$ is a singular matrix. Plugging in the explicit form of $A$ in ${\mathbb R}^2$ it is easy to see that $\det(I-rA)=0$ only if $r=1$.

EDIT.

In the special case $s=i\circ\sigma$, where $i$ is a translation of vector $\vec t$ and $\sigma$ a stretch of scale factor $r$, it is easy to construct a fixed point $P$ of $s$ if $r\ne1$:
$$
P=O+{1\over1-r}\vec t,
$$
where $O$ is the fixed point of $\sigma$. In fact:
$$
P'=\sigma(P)=O+{r\over1-r}\vec t
\quad\text{and}\quad
s(P)=i(P')=P'+\vec t=O+{1\over1-r}\vec t=P.
$$
If $i$ is a glide reflection, we can set up a coordinate system such that $x$ axis is the reflection line, $\vec t=(t,0)$ is the translation vector, while the fixed point of $\sigma$ is on $y$ axis at $O=(0,d)$.
A simple computation shows then that $P=(x,y)$ is a fixed point if:
$$
x={r\over1-r} t,\quad y={1-r\over1+r}d.
$$

Comment: That's a very neat way to prove, but I would prefer a synthetic proof (or, at least, without using linear algebra concepts).

Comment: This theorem is also an immediate consequence of the [contraction mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) but I could not find a simple geometric argument.

Comment: Could you explain the proof you find involved? That would help in finding something simpler.

Comment: I'd rather give a reference to https://sites.millersville.edu/rumble/Math.505/Book/chapter5.pdf (section 5.3) as one of the possible sources for, what seems to be, the traditional approach.

Comment: See if my edit can be useful.

Comment: Your edit is excellent! It is indeed easy to construct the fixed points for translations and glide reflections, and it is not more difficult for reflections and rotations!